# Dropdown box selection to populate textbox in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am encountering a minor problem with some javascripts/AJAX and i was hoping someone can help me or point me to the right direction.

What I am trying to do is to populate my per-carton-price-field using collection_select in the same form. This is an order form which is suppose to create an entry into my order table. Form view as below:

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add a new order for <%= @customer.name %></h1>

<div class="row">
  <%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :customer_id, :value => @customer.id %>

      <h3>Order Details</h3>
      <%= f.label :address_id, "Delivery Address" %>
      <%= f.collection_select :address_id, @addresses, :id, :select_address, :prompt => "Select delivery location",class: 'form-control' %></br>      
      <%= f.label :remark, "Order Remark" %>
      <%= f.text_area :remark, class: 'form-control' %></br>

      <h3>What items would you like to place?</h3>
      <%= f.add_nested_fields_link :single_orders, "Add Product" %>
      <%= f.nested_fields_for :single_orders do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.collection_select :product_id, @products, :id, :select_product, {:prompt => "choose product"},   {:class => "product_selection form-control"}  %>
        <%= builder.text_field :ctn_price, placeholder: "Price/carton", id: "price", class: 'ctn_price_field form-control' %>
        <%= builder.text_field :qty, placeholder: "Quantity",id: "quantity", class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= builder.text_field :price, placeholder: "Amount", id: "total-amount", readonly: true, class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= builder.remove_nested_fields_link %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
      <%= f.submit "place order", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I would like the collection_select:product_id to pull out all the products in the products table. When the user selects whichever product they want to order from the dropdown, the price for the selected product will populate the text_field:ctn_price.

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :special_prices, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :single_orders
  has_many :package_orders_products

  before_save   :upcase_stock_code

  validates :name,        presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :stock_code,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :status,      presence: true, length: { maximum: 10 }
  validates :price,       presence: true

  private
    def select_product
      "#{name} - #{price}"
    end

    # Converts stock_code to all upper-case.
    def upcase_stock_code
      self.stock_code = stock_code.upcase
    end
end
```

single_order.rb

```
class SingleOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product

  validates :order,       presence: true
  validates :product_id,  presence: true
  validates :qty,         presence: true
  validates :price,       presence: true
  validates :ctn_price,   presence: true
end
```

Any help is appreciated as I have been stuck for days :(
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: When user select a product in drop down list, you can call an ajax request to server with product id, then get the price of product and update value for price's text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using ajax call. Before that create a api to take product_id as input and render @product as output.

```
   $("#product_selection_id").on('change', function(){
    var product_id = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      type: 'html',
      url: "call_url_for_get_product_api_with_product_id",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        console.log("success");
      }
    });
  });
```

Suppose your `url_for_get_product_api` goes to `get_product` action as a js request. so create a template with `get_product.js.erb` as follows

```
$('#ctn_price_field').val(@product.price)
#ihave not tested this code change this according to your requirements.
```

Note: Here i have given a pattern impliment this by your own. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your respond!! i am trying out the concept you provided above but im stuck at the routes part i was wondering if you could help me.. route route for orders is as below

resources :orders do
    member do
      get :new
      get 'get_product_prices', to: "orders#get_product_prices"
      post :create, :inactive, :active
    end
    collection do
    end
  end

but it does not seem to be able to get the "get_product_prices" URL and only getting the "new" url.. the error I encounter is this:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:8:in `new'

Comment: can you please update your question with your new routes file code?